# ts + webpack bundling for node cannot find module 'path'

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, node-modules, bundler

I know this has been asked before but I *cannot* get any accepted answer to work.

My objective is to get each of my entry points to bundle as a single [entry].js for portability. Ideally I would like to have [entry].js and [entry].[modules/vendor].js but not necessary.

What I have tried:

- Using `webpack-node-externals` with `allowlist`. Results in deep modules not being found
- Manual externals options `path: "commonjs path"`. Does not change result
- `const {} = require('path')` instead of `import {} from 'path'`. Also doesn't change anything
- The configs below which I believe gets the closest result which is just that it cannot find built-ins.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "launch",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "__tests__",
    "dist",
    "launch"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/Auth",
    "src/Gate",
    "src/Patch",
    "src/Account",
    "src/Proxy",
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    'gate': './src/Gate/index.ts',
    'patch': './src/Patch/index.ts',
    'auth': './src/Auth/index.ts',
    'account': './src/Account/index.ts',
    'proxy': './src/Proxy/index.ts',
  },
  stats: {warnings:false},
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
    chunkIds: 'natural',
    splitChunks: {
      // default splitChunks config
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 20000,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 30,
      maxInitialRequests: 30,
      enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Normally, when bundling for Node env, we should not define vendor chunks at all since it runs the node_modules should always be there for using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the package `cli` that has its own type of managed module resolution that breaks with webpack. I have replaced it with `commander`.